# Duplicate and position SVGs on A4 PDF

Tags: python, pdf, svg, inkscape

The problem I try to solve is the automated duplication and positioning of one svg (140 x 70 mm) six times to get a printer friendly A4 PDF page.

I want to create a multi-page invitation (140 x 70 mm). On one A4 sheet (different color A4 sheets) I want to position 6 cutouts. One invitation constists out of 4 sheets, each duplex printed. This leads to 8 pages to put information. So I will gain 6 inviations from 4x A4. It will look similar to [this one](http://www.verruecktnachhochzeit.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Hanna-Witte-Benrath-18_Verrueckt-nach-Hochzeit_Bube-Dame-Herz_Hochzeitsmesse-auf-Schloss-Benrath.jpg).

So an A4 sheet will look like this.

```
 ________210mm_________
|              |       |
|      A       |       |
|______________|   C   |
|              |       |
2      B       |       |
9______________|_______|
7______________________|
m              |       |
m      D       |       |
|______________|   F   |
|              |       |
|      E       |       |
|______________|_______|
```

I prepared a page (140 x 70 mm) and the corresponding back side using inkscape. I could duplicate manually with inkscape for each page. But it's repeating work and if I want to change a page I have to propagate it all the time to A, B, C, ...

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem maybe with python? I already found some svglib's. But I just found a simple svg -> pdf conversion.

Comment: That would be a simple task using XSL and XSL FO technology. Input the SVG and place it in the six containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to investigate Inkscapes "Clone" feature.

http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clones.html

It may do what you want.

One obvious question that springs to mind though. If your invitation is 160x70, how are you going to fit C on the page?  160+70 > 210.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did it by cloning and it was comfortable. How could I combine the A4 layout to deploy changes? Now I have 8 different files and I have to propagte each layout seperately. As far as I see Inkscape/SVG does not support multipage,

Comment: Have you considered having eight different layers on the same page?  When you need to produce your eight PDF files, you could just turn each layer on in turn and save your PDFs.  A little tedious maybe, but  at least all your clones would be in the same document.